# How can you use one block of code to target all the classes on a website? (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, function, web-applications, click, reload

I've been working on a game as part of some class work and have run into an issue. The issue is the code only effect one button. I'm using the following on a two '.restart' buttons to reload the browser....

```
//Reload Page
document.querySelector('.restart').addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

One restart button is on the top(like a header).  The other is in a Modal. The Modal shows up first in the HTML.  I'm 99.9% this is why the second one gets skipped. I've tried using `document.querySelectorAll....`However I get a `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function` and neither works.  How can I use one snippet to control all the same classes with Javascript? Below is a code pen of the game...

https://codepen.io/AB3D/pen/xJWMpd

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` - which you'll need to iterate through (the `NodeList` returned has a `forEach` method for example) ... so `document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', .....))`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using ...
//Reload Page
document.querySelectorAll('.restart').forEach(node => addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.reload();
}));
However it seems to reload the page with every button click..... is there something wrong with the syntax maybe? (I'm not to familiar using =>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `querySelectorAll()` returns an array of elements.
The solution would be to iterate through these elements and attach the event to each one of them.

```html
<button class="restart">Button 1</button>
<button class="restart">Button 2</button>
<button class="restart">Button 3</button>
<script>
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".restart");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
</script>
```

Since you're using a class name as a selector , you can also use `getElementsByClassName("restart")` as an alternative , this method also returns an array of elements.